# Bukkit - Detect Right click

Tags: java, bukkit

How would I detect if a player has right clicked a book after they run a specific command?
I have

```
 if (playere.getItemInHand().getType() != Material.AIR && (event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK ||  event.getAction() == Action.RIGHT_CLICK_AIR)) {
```

but I don't know where to put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to listen for PlayerInteractEvent and use the above line. 
Aditionally i wouldn't recomend you wrap if's this way, specifically i would recomend you check if the action is right click or left click in one if, and then check if the item is null in an inner if to avoid confusion and make your code readable.

Now to make it work after a command, you will have to put the player's name or UUID in a list once they perform the command, and in the PlayerInteractEvent, check if they are in the list. If they are, go ahead and execute the code. Otherwise do nothing.